# Is there a reason why this function and one exactly the same format won't work?

Tags: c#

I can't get a function in C# to work, Visual Studio doesn't detect anything wrong with the actual coding of it, just the naming part, `HeightInInches`, is underlined in red.

I'm just trying out a simple BMI calculator but this function just won't work, there is another function with the same structure but has the same issue with just having the 'naming' of the function being underlined.

I've tried changing different data types like int, but no luck.

```
    static double HeightInInches(double F, double I)
    {
        if (F < 2 || F > 7 || I < 0 || I > 11)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Height");
        }
        else
        {
            double IncheHeight = F * 12 + I;
            return IncheHeight;
        }
    }
```

Comment: "View - Error List" or hover your mouse over the red line.

Comment: I got the code working now, thanks to all the comments and suggestions, plus Rufus L for the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that not all paths through your code return a value. The compiler even tells you this:

[image]

In this case, since the problem is an invalid argument, the typical way to handle it is to throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. Notice you can get rid of the `else` now, since execution will stop if the `if` condition evaluates to `true`:

```
static double HeightInInches(double feet, double inches)
{
    if (feet < 2 || feet > 7 || inches < 0 || inches > 11)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Invalid Height");
    }

    return feet * 12 + inches;
}
```

With a little extra code, you can let the user know exactly which parameter is incorrect:

```
static double HeightInInches(double feet, double inches)
{
    if (feet < 2 || feet > 7)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("feet must be between 2 and 7, inclusive.");
    }

    if (inches < 0 || inches > 11)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("inches must be between 0 and 11, inclusive.");
    }

    return feet * 12 + inches;
}
```

Comment: @j.doe Aside: When designing messages I always ask what question the message raises, then try to incorporate the answer. "Invalid height." What was the height? "Invalid height: 9 feet, -1 inches." What are the ranges? "Invalid height: 9 feet (range: 2 to 7), -1 inches (range: 0 to 11)." As long as it isn't a major effort just go ahead and make the message as useful as practical. Note that validating all of the input for a single message is often a good thing. And if there is additional context, e.g. _whose_ height, that ought to be incorporated as the exception propagates up through the code.

Answer (score 0):

Not all code paths return a value.

If your first code path is hit, there will be no return. You may want to throw an exception there instead of writing to the console.

Answer (score 0):

as the error states, not all code paths returns value.

you need to add `return` statement in your `if` condition or else `throw exception`

check this

```
public static double? HeightInInches(double F, double I)
{
    if (F < 2 || F > 7 || I < 0 || I > 11)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Height");
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        double IncheHeight = F * 12 + I;
        return IncheHeight;
    }
}
```

or with exception handling

```
    public static double HeightInInches(double F, double I)
{
    if (F < 2 || F > 7 || I < 0 || I > 11)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Height");
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid Height");
    }
    else
    {
        double IncheHeight = F * 12 + I;
        return IncheHeight;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a return statement in the if {}

```
    static double HeightInInches(double F, double I)
{
    if (F < 2 || F > 7 || I < 0 || I > 11)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Height");
        //return something here
    }
    else
    {
        double IncheHeight = F * 12 + I;
        return IncheHeight;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All paths should return a value, in your case is the return value a double. So, your `else` returns a double and your `if` does not. You should add `return null;` after `Console.WriteLine("Invalid Height");`.